# Не экспортируется проект из Eclipse c Gradle

Tags: android-studio, eclipse, gradle

Есть проект, написанный на Eclipse, к которому подключены проекты как библиотеки. Нужно экпортировать проект для Android Studio. Нажимаю ПКМ на проект -> Export -> Android -> Generate Gradle builds files -> next -> выбираю свой проект из списка -> дальше окошко с несколькими проектами, наверху  `Enable overriding of existing files before clicking Finish`, ниже ставлю галочку `Force overriding of existing files`, активируется кнопка Finish, я нажимаю на эту кнопку, и ничего не происходит. Как решить данную проблему?